# How to feed data into random forest classifier and see prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have build a random forest classifier using scikit learn and python, and I am having trouble actually feeding data in to see the prediction. I want to see the format of the output, and to convert this to a json file. I have attached the code for the random forest and what the data looks like. I believe I need to use 'y_pred', but I am not sure what format the input data needs to be.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:4].values
y = dataset["pages"]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state = 0)
classifier = classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you expect exactly? Input for `classifier.predict()` is a numpy array with same number of dimensions as `X_train` (or `X_test`).

Comment: Right now, using classifier.predict() gives me a list of all the 'pages' predictions for the test data I have inputted, in this format [1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1]. I would like to change this to also include the data from that row in json format, like so: {seconds:50, size2:12, pages:1}, rather than a list of just the outputs.

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the predicted values with the matrix of features.

Also note that the pipeline is exactly for this purpose, when you first want to transform the data and then apply some classifier.

This should work for you:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd

X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:4].values
y = dataset["pages"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
classifier = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state=0))
classifier = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

pred = pd.concat([X_test, pd.Series(y_pred, name="pages")], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried that, and got the error 'TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid', do you know why this could be?

Comment: Probably `X_test` isn't a `pd.DataFrame`, in that case, just convert it to a `pd.DataFrame`. If the answer is what you're looking for, consider accepting it. :)